# Why CONCAT does not insert text for the first time into mySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am using UPDATE to insert simple text into a table where the field is MEDIUMTEXT (nullable field).
It is strange that it does not work when the field is null initially. If I manually enter at least a one character/space, then it's working.

I want to append the new text into existing text in the field.

```
UPDATE pen SET  
                PEN_STATUS = @PenStat,
                PEN_STATUS_CHANGE_REASON = CONCAT(PEN_STATUS_CHANGE_REASON,'\n',ChangeDate,':',EmployeeID,':',ChangeReason)
            WHERE PEN_ID = PenID;
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, because something is `NULL`.  Try using `CONCAT_WS()` instead:

```
UPDATE pen
    SET PEN_STATUS = @PenStat,
        PEN_STATUS_CHANGE_REASON = CONCAT_WS('\n',
                                             PEN_STATUS_CHANGE_REASON,
                                             CONCAT_WS(':', ChangeDate, EmployeeID, ChangeReason
                                                     )
                                            )
    WHERE PEN_ID = PenID;
```

`CONCAT_WS()` ignores `NULL` arguments.  Plus, the separator only needs to be listed once.

Answer (score 5):

`CONCAT` does not handle `NULL` values. As explained in [the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

> `CONCAT()` returns NULL if any argument is NULL.

You want to use `COALESCE` to handle that use case, like :

```
UPDATE pen SET  
    PEN_STATUS = @PenStat,
    PEN_STATUS_CHANGE_REASON = CONCAT(
        COALESCE(PEN_STATUS_CHANGE_REASON, ''),
        '\n', 
        ChangeDate,
        ':',
        EmployeeID,
        ':',
        ChangeReason
    )
WHERE PEN_ID = PenID;
```